# Selecting from p:dataTable list and show details to another p:dataTable list

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a `table` showing `list` from a `bean`. When I click one of the `rows`, I want to view details from another bean list what would I write to value to second detail `datatable list` ?

Let say I have a `bean` of list students `datatable` containing name, surname and numbers, when I click a row, on the second `datatable` there is a `bean list` of `student`'s `address`, `city` and `country`

Now I can `System.out.print` the `adress detail` of `student` when I click to `row` in student table but I can't show it on `datatable`

I'm asking how I can take the values to a `datatable`, what will be the value in `datatable`?
Thanks for your help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <f:view>
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:dataTable id="users" var="user" value="#{userOS.osList}"
                paginator="true" rows="10" rowKey="#{user.kisiid}"
                selection="#{userOS.selectedOS}" selectionMode="single">
                <f:facet name="header">  
                                        Kullanıcı detaylarını görmek için view butonuna tıklayınız
                                        </f:facet>
                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{userOS.onRowSelect}" update=":form:display"
                    oncomplete="userDialog" />

                <p:column headerText="Student No" sortBy="ogrencino"
                    filterBy="ogrencino" id="ogrencino">
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.ogrencino}" />
                    <f:param name="kid" value="#{userOS.osList.rowIndex}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="ad" filterBy="ad" id="ad">
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.ad}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Surname" sortBy="soyad" filterBy="soyad"
                    id="soyad">
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.soyad}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Faculty" sortBy="altbirim.ad"
                    filterBy="altbirim.ad" id="altbirim">
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.altbirim.ad}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Department" sortBy="bolum.ad"
                    filterBy="bolum.ad" id="bolum">
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.bolum.ad}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Status" sortBy="ogrencidurum.ad"
                    filterBy="ogrencidurum.ad" id="ogrencidurum">
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.ogrencidurum.ad}" />
                </p:column>

                <f:facet name="footer">
                </f:facet>
            </p:dataTable>

            <p:panel id="dialog" header="User Detail" widgetVar="userDialog">

                <h:panelGrid id="panelgrid" columns="2" cellpadding="4">
                    <p:dataTable id="display" var="adres" value="#{userOS.adresList}">
                        <p:column headerText="Adres Tipi">
                            <h:outputText value="#{adres.AddressType}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Adres">
                            <h:outputText value="#{adres.Address}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="İl">
                            <h:outputText value="#{adres.City}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Ülke">
                            <h:outputText value="#{adres.Country}" />
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </h:panelGrid>

            </p:panel>


        </h:form>
    </f:view>
</h:body>
</html>
```

And `KisiInfoProcess.java` code :

```
package com.revir.process;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.revir.managed.bean.AddressBean;
import com.revir.managed.bean.OgrenimSureciBean;
import com.revir.domain.Adres;
import com.revir.domain.AdresDAO;
import com.revir.domain.Kisi;
import com.revir.domain.KisiDAO;
import com.revir.domain.Kisiadresi;
import com.revir.domain.Ogrenimsureci;
import com.revir.domain.OgrenimsureciDAO;
import com.revir.domain.Ulke;
import com.revir.process.KisiInfoProcess;

@ManagedBean(name = "userOS")
@SessionScoped
public class KisiInfoProcess implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(KisiInfoProcess.class);

    private List<OgrenimSureciBean> osList;

    private List<AddressBean> adresList;

    private List<AddressBean> adresListesi;

    public List<AddressBean> getAdresListesi() {
        return adresListesi;
    }

    public void setAdresListesi(List<AddressBean> adresListesi) {
        this.adresListesi = adresListesi;
    }

    private OgrenimSureciBean selectedOS;

    private AddressBean selectedAdres;

    public OgrenimSureciBean getSelectedOS() {
        return selectedOS;
    }

    public void setSelectedOS(OgrenimSureciBean selectedOS) {
        this.selectedOS = selectedOS;
    }

    public AddressBean getSelectedAdres() {
        return selectedAdres;
    }

    public void setSelectedAdres(AddressBean selectedAdres) {
        this.selectedAdres = selectedAdres;
    }

    public List<OgrenimSureciBean> getOsList() {
        OgrenimsureciDAO ogrenimsureciDAO = new OgrenimsureciDAO();

        List<OgrenimSureciBean> osList = new ArrayList<OgrenimSureciBean>();

        for (Iterator i = ogrenimsureciDAO.findByMezunOgrenciler((short) 8)
                .iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            Ogrenimsureci og = (Ogrenimsureci) i.next();
            OgrenimSureciBean osBean = new OgrenimSureciBean();

            osBean.setBolum(og.getBolum());
            osBean.setAd(og.getKisiByKisiid().getAd());
            osBean.setSoyad(og.getKisiByKisiid().getSoyad());
            osBean.setAltbirim(og.getAltbirim());
            osBean.setOgrencino(og.getOgrencino());
            osBean.setKisiid(og.getKisiByKisiid().getKisiid());
            osBean.setOgrencidurum(og.getOgrencidurum());

            osList.add(osBean);
            System.out.println("osBean : " + osBean.toString());

        }
        return osList;
    }

    public void setOsList(List<OgrenimSureciBean> osList) {
        this.osList = osList;
    }

    public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {

        System.out.println("On Row Select Metodu çalıştı");

        try {
            getAdresList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public List<AddressBean> getAdresList() throws Exception {

        if (getSelectedOS() != null) {
            log.debug("PersonalInfoProcess - getAddressInfo - Start");
            List<AddressBean> adresList = new ArrayList<AddressBean>();

            KisiDAO kisiDAO = new KisiDAO();
            AdresDAO adresDAO = new AdresDAO();

            Long kisiid = getSelectedOS().getKisiid();
            System.out.println("kisiid :" + kisiid);
            Kisi kisi = kisiDAO.findById(kisiid);

            for (Iterator i = kisi.getKisiadresis().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

                Kisiadresi kisiAdresi = (Kisiadresi) i.next();
                System.out.println("i :" + i);
                Adres tmpAdres = adresDAO.findById(kisiAdresi.getId()
                        .getAdresid());

                if (tmpAdres != null) {
                    AddressBean address = new AddressBean(kisiid);

                    if (tmpAdres.getAdresturu() == null) {
                        address.setAddressType(null);
                    } else {
                        address.setAddressType(tmpAdres.getAdresturu().getAd());
                        System.out.println("Adres Türü:" +tmpAdres.getAdresturu().getAd());
                    }

                    address.setAddress(tmpAdres.getAdres());
                    System.out.println("Şehir:" +tmpAdres.getAdres());

                    if (tmpAdres.getIl() == null) {
                        address.setCity(null);
                    } else {
                        address.setCity(tmpAdres.getIl().getAd());
                        System.out.println("Şehir:" +tmpAdres.getIl().getAd());
                    }

                    if (tmpAdres.getUlke() == null) {
                        address.setCountry(null);
                    } else {
                        address.setCountry(tmpAdres.getUlke().getAd());
                        System.out.println("Ülke:" +tmpAdres.getUlke().getAd());
                    }

                    adresList.add(address);

                    System.out.println("adres" + address);
                    System.out.println("adreslist" + adresList);
                }

                log.debug("PersonalInfoProcess - getAddressInfo - End / Returning");
            }
        }
        return adresList;
    }

    public void setAdresList(List<AddressBean> adresList) {
        this.adresList = adresList;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: I added my code I'll be happy If you help me on this

Comment: Try an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). There is a lot of noise in your code here